# Workbook Macro on Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If InRange(ActiveSheet.ActiveCell, Range("M4:M1048576")) Then
        MsgBox "ESTA EN EL RANGO DE M"
        If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1))) And (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value > 0) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "EFECTIVO") > 0 Then
                Call RestaEfectivo
            ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "BAC Débito") > 0 Then
                Call RestaBAC
            ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "CITI Débito") > 0 Then
                Call RestaCITI
            ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "BAC Crédito") > 0 Then
                Call IncrementarCredito
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

which was set to a specific worksheet. However, I decided to ut it out from the worksheet and place it on ThisWorkbook. I'm very new to VBA so I have no idea what I need to change in the code so it executes on every worksheet, right now, the code won't execute at all.

Could anyone tell me what I need to change in my code so that it stays on ThisWorkbook and it executes on every sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the event listener sub is not the same name in ThisWorkbook module.

just move the body of the code into this event listener in ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Place the code here
End Sub
```

it will work.

cheers~

---

you can see what event listener are available using the drop down menu

[image]

pick one and VBA will automatically create the sub for you.

HTH.